# iOS UI causes crash after pushing/popping second view controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, user-interface, uinavigationcontroller

In my iOS app, the entire user interface is coded programmatically, meaning no xibs or storyboards. All works well until I add another view controller via a *UINavigationController*.

The first view controller works well, and when the second view controller is pushed, it works well too. But after the second view controller pops itself, and the first view controller re-appears, any interaction with any of the elements of the user interface crashes the app.

Any idea what may be causing this?

**UPDATE:** Screenshot of exception[image: exception]

Comment: Your view controller is likely referencing something that has been deallocated.  You should be able to run the app in the debugger, look at the stack trace, and determine the issue.  Are you asking how to track this down?

Comment: @PetahChristian: Yes; there are no specific error messages, and I don't know how to track it as you have suggested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a crash log that's generated when the app crashes.  All the messages, along with the stack backtrace are there.

*You can see a device's crash logs by connecting it to your Mac, then opening the Devices window, and viewing the device logs.*

But it's easier to just debug this within Xcode, by connecting your device, then building and running it in Xcode, on the device.

When the app crashes (due to some exception), Xcode can catch this, and control will be transferred to the debugger.

You can add an **Exception Breakpoint** in Xcode to stop your app as soon as the exception occurs.

To add an exception breakpoint, switch to the Breakpoint Navigator.  Click the small + button at the bottom of the pane, and select **Add Exception Breakpoint**.

Once the app crashes, you can look at the stack backtrace.  The first few items on the call stack will likely be in Apple's code, but slightly further back will be a call from your view controller, showing the line which revealed the problem.

As to what is specifically wrong, it could be any number of things.  We can't specifically help unless you share code that show the properties for those objects, and where they are (de)allocated.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I added the exception breakpoint, but I can't seem to find the stack backtrace. Is it the assembly listing with the various threads?

Comment: Yes.  The assembly code is Apple's SDK.  If you look at the list of calls for the thread that crashed, you'll see numbers, starting at 0.  Work down the list, until you get to your own code.

Comment: Thank you. I think I found it, although not much to go on _(screenshot added to question)_. No way of knowing what caused it?

Comment: Enable NSZombies.  You're likely accessing something that has been dereferenced and points to garbage (or you've somehow set an object's pointer to 150).

Comment: I'll try and figure out NSZombies, but what do you mean by setting an object's pointer to 150?

Comment: It's crashing because your app is trying to access memory address 0x150.  So, whatever object your code is accessing thinks its object is at that memory address.  Either your code changed the object, overwrote the object, or deallocated the object.  Not practical to explain pointers and addresses in these comments.

Comment: Thank you. It was a deallocated object; tracked it through _Profile -> Zombies_. I then changed the instance variable to a property and it resolved the issue. Thank you.